# After navigating between views, components arent loaded properly

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin-flow

When i navigate between views, CSS isnt loaded properly, if i refresh the site, it works fine. This is the code in my first view :

```
@UIScoped
@Route("login")
@HtmlImport("frontend://styles/shared-styles.html")
public class LoginView extends Div {
```

and this is the code in a button i have in this loginview :

```
signinButton.addClickListener(event -> {
            // login
            if (userLogin.isLoggedIn()) { 
                UI.getCurrent().navigate("View2");
            } else {
                Notification.show("Error");
            }
        });
```

class userLogin merely returns a boolean variable that tells me if im logged in or not.

and this is how the second view is written

```
@Route("View1")
@PWA(name = "TestApp", shortName = "TestApp")
@HtmlImport("frontend://styles/shared-styles.html")
@UIScoped
public class View1 extends Div implements View, BeforeEnterObserver {
```

in the attachments bellow theres also screenshots of how it should look and how it looks, apologies for blurring data. As you can see, the CSS for vaadin.flow.grid isnt loaded at all, or rather its like the component doesnt fully load (u can also see that same thing happening in the orange label), this also happens, if after i get from loginview to view1, i dont refresh and go straight to view2, the grid looks the same, doesnt load properly. Again, if i refresh everything goes to how it should look.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIIc2.jpg this is the album with the attachment pictures

Comment: What Vaadin version you are using? Also, do you have your own styles added?

Comment: vaadin 14.0.0.alpha1. Ye in the shared-styles.html file thats imported into the views has css classes in them.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem using `UI.getCurrent().navigate`, but it works using the  RouterLinkApi

Comment: This seems like a regression, try to downgrade for now to `<vaadin.version>13.0.3</vaadin.version>` 
Seems to work there

Comment: thank you, downgrading worked just fine, i guess i'll hold out on 14 until the official release, or i'll give it another go in beta

Comment: Glad it worked! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Posting from the comments, as it helps to *workaround* the problem for now)

This looks like regression in Flow version `14.0.0.alpha1`. (`Grid` version is `3.0.3`)
Try to downgrade for now to previous stable 13.0.3

Created an issue here : [Grid rendered without styles](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-flow/issues/626)